# I am developing library management system in C#. I want to calculate fine by comparing issue date and return date

Tags: c#, textbox

Fine is calculated as:-

Find the number of days between issue date and return date.

If number of days is greater than 1 then calculate fine using the formula given below

```
Fine=Number of Days * 10 Rs. (i.e 10 Rs fine per day)
```

Otherwise there will be no fine.

this is my code but getting a string error

```
        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int st = dtpreturndate.Value.Date.Subtract(dtpduedate.Value.Date).Days;

            if ((st > 0))
            {
                txtfine.Text = ((st * 5)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                txtfine.Text = 0;
            }   

        }
```

Comment: txtfine.Text = "0" ???

Comment: You just asked this same question less than a half hr ago. Please try to search google for some help. Then if you have a problem ask it here.

Comment: Ps fine calculation should be a discreet function, and then you just display the result.

Comment: if the date exceed the txtfine.Text = ((st * 5)).ToString(); will run other wise it is initialized to 0 that's where im getting the error

Comment: That's because 0 is an int, not a string. Use "0"

Comment: `0` is an Integer, but `txtfine.Text` expects a String. Change it to `"0"`

Comment: Text is a string, you can't assign 0 to  it. C# is a statically and strongly typed language, 0 is not a string.

Comment: its your business logic and your mistakes are pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help guys

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                int st = dtpreturndate.Value.Date.Subtract(dtpduedate.Value.Date).Days;

                if ((st > 0))
                {
                    txtfine.Text = ((st * 5)).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtfine.Text = "0";
                }   

            }
```